# Drawing in JPanel vs JComponent

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, jcomponent

I need some help understanding why the drawing works differently in JComponent vs JPanel.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Particle extends JComponent implements Runnable{
    private int x = 45;
    private int y = 45;
    private int cx;
    private int cy;
    private int size;
    private Color color;
    private JFrame frame;

    public Color getColor(){
        return color = new Color(100,0,190);
    }

    public Particle(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void update(){
        x+=1;
        y+=1;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(getColor());

        g2d.fillRect(x, y, 4, 4);
    }

    public void startThread(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 200; i++){
            try{
                update();
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(4);    
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.print("Exception at thread.start()");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Particle particle = new Particle();
        particle.startThread();
    }
}
```

In this above example, the "particle" moves from point A to point B just fine..

But when I subclass Particle from JComponent to JPanel..

the drawing forms a line.. i.e. the rectangle never disappears from where it starts..

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call super.paintComponent(g) in paintComponent implementation.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);

  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
  g2d.setColor(getColor());
  g2d.fillRect(x, y, 4, 4);

}
```

Comment: Ah.. so JComponent called the super automatically didn't it? And I just forgot to do so with JPanel.


Also, I know that whenever I'm overriding a method, I should call a super like that.. but can you explain what exactly happened when I called `super.paintComponent(g);` and what is happening when I did not call it. I ask so that I may better understand what is happening .

Answer (score 5):

A solution has been post by [Toilal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16998448/2040040). I want to explain *why*:

In [the API docs of `paintComponent` of `JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29)

> Further, if you do not invoker super's implementation you must honor the opaque property, that is if this component is opaque, you must completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts.

In [`setOpaque` of `JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque%28boolean%29)

> The default value of this property is false for `JComponent`. However, the default value for this property on most standard `JComponent` subclasses (such as `JButton` and `JTree`) is look-and-feel dependent.

Add this code:

```
System.out.println(isOpaque());
```

- In `JComponent` case `false` is printed.
- In `JPanel` case `true` is printed.

That's all.

Comment: Thank you for the explenation. Much appreciated.

Comment: +1, for this profound information part, added something to my knowledge  :-)