# Not sure how to use swing to draw rectangles

Tags: java, swing

I am practicing for a test I have coming up and I am looking through some practice questions. I have come across a question that is challenging me more than the others. I am needing to write a method, using swing it seems, that creates 100 rectangles of a given width and varying heights found through simple mathematics. I have made my array that holds each height and I have my width set. How might I go about creating these rectangles using swing? I would prefer that this question be answered in a way that tries to push me in the right direction (i.e. try using JLabel or something of that nature) rather than doing it for me. How would I ever learn it that way? I may end up with some follow up questions as well. Here is the code that makes my Array for heights and sets my width. It is probably assumed but my parameters are in pixels.

```
public void paintComponent() {
   int[] heights = new int[100];
   int width = 10
   int initialHeight = 100;
   for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
      int usedHeight = height - i;
      heights[i] = usedHeight;
   }
```

Again, please do not do it for me. I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I assume I will be using swing in some way to do this.

Comment: Which part is troubling you exactly? Finding information on drawing a rectangle using swing shouldn't be terribly difficult.

Comment: How far have you got down the swing route, have you got a blank space and need to fill it or is getting the swing window up also causing difficulties

Comment: In swing we have gotten through JFrame, JPanel, JLabel, Layouts, Buttons, and Menus. I can create all of these but am having trouble thinking through how to actually create and draw the rectangles using swing.

Comment: I suggest you create `BufferedImage` for each rectangle, and save them in a array, and for each refresh/repaint clear the panel and redraw images, or just show them with JLabel, for drawing creates a `Graphic` object from the generated `BufferedImage` and call the draw/fill rectangle method :)

Comment: @CodyBerry It pretty much runs off of the Cartesian system where 0,0 is the upper left hand corner of the JFrame. To draw a rectangle with drawRect(x,y,width,height) (see javadocs), as you increment X, the upper-lefthand corner of your rectangle will shift right.  However, incrementing Y will shift it down. Do you mean something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is subclass [`JComponent` and override `paintComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29). The [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object passed to it lets you do what you need ([hint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)).

Comment: Oh wow, I completely overlooked JComponent. We never had to used the class in our homework so it never crossed my mind. The simple things just go overlooked too easily. That should be plenty to get me going. Thanks!

Comment: @CodyBerry : Do consider `JPanel` over `JComponent` for painting of this sorts, since there are subtle differences between the two as cited in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16998657/1057230) +1 though for the hint, I have to wait for this since my limit is gone for today :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw nice catch, but it's sufficient to call `super.paintComponent(graphics)` first thing in the overriding `paintComponent`.

Comment: @gustafc : Yeah, I am not against this approach, just providing a bit extra, I found a few days back, never looked that deeply into the Java Docs for `JComponent` before that. But true, `JComponent` will suffice :-)

Answer (score 2):

General approach:

- Make a JFrame with a JPanel
- Give it a layout (something simple like a GridLayout will probably
  work for this)
- Add the Components to your container (I'll point you towards [Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)) (or you can just use JPanels and set their border/fill color)

One of the hardest things to learn in Swing is layout managers, so expect to spend some time bashing your head against that wall until it gives way.  Prepare to have swing draw all the rectangles on top of one another, draw them in a single column, and not draw them at all.  Probably not in that order.

Comment: Rectangle is not a Swing component.  Rectangle holds the values of a rectangle (x origin, y origin, width, height).

Comment: You are correct, rectangle is awt.  The swing-y way is to override paintComponent, as in the accepted answer, or simply with bordered JPanels.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first, you have some bugs in your current code (assuming height is decreasing):

```
public void paintComponent() {
  int[] heights = new int[100];
  int width = 10;
  int initialHeight = 100;
  for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    heights[i] = initialHeight;
    initialHeight--;
    //also heights[i] = 100-i;
  }
}
```

When `usedHeight` was declared inside the cycle, it existed ony during one 'cycle' of the cycle.

Second, if you want to understand how swing works, download 5+- already working examples and figure it out from code (worked for me just fine).